# Listbox data insertion to database (ASP.net MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hello I have `listbox` which I'm filling from `textbox` values after clicking a button when listbox fills then I'm trying to insert the list box data to database but the problem is that only one item is inserting, my requirement is that, that insert all data from `listbox to database` without selecting it

this is my View code:

```
 <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">  
   @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.TermsandConditionAr, new List<SelectListItem>(), new { id = "termsconAr", Multiple = "multiple", Size = 15, style = "width: 100%;" }) 
 </div>
```

The model code

```
public partial class Services 
{ 
    [Key] 
    public long ID { get; set; } 
    [Display(Name = "Terms and Condition En")] 
    public string TermsandConditionEn { get; set; } 
    [Display(Name = "Terms and Condition Ar")] 
    public string TermsandConditionAr { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Can you post the model code?

Comment: this is my model code                                                                               public partial class Services
    {
        [Key]
        public long ID { get; set; }


 
        [Display(Name = "Terms and Condition En")]
        public string TermsandConditionEn { get; set; }

 
        [Display(Name = "Terms and Condition Ar")]
        public string TermsandConditionAr { get; set; }

 
      
    }

Comment: You are supposed to have a list of items which you need it to be part of the model that you need as options for using it as List<SelectListItem>(). You right now have only one such value.